# Pytest not collecting any items

Tags: python

```
from plates import is_valid


def two_letr():
    assert is_valid("Aa2222") == True
    assert is_valid("22aa22") == "hello"

def min_max():
    assert is_valid("aa3") == False
    assert is_valid("aaaa2222") == False
    assert is_valid("aa") == True
    assert is_valid("aaaa22") == True

def mid():
    assert is_valid("aaa22a") == False
    assert is_valid("aaa222") == True
    assert is_valid("aa2a00") == False


def zero():
    assert is_valid("aaa022") == False
    assert is_valid("aa0222") == False

def sup_space():
    assert is_valid("aaa./0") == False
    assert is_valid("aa0  ") == False
    assert is_valid("./?! ") == False
```

I have tried to run `pytest` but seems it is not testing anyting. It is like I am not asserting anything, even actually to do so (plates its a program in cs50p if some one knows)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It is good practice to put the tests in a class named after the module. So, if your file is named `binary_tree.py`, your tests go in a file `test_binary_tree.py` that contains a class `TestBinaryTree` that contains test methods all beginning with `test`, like `test_inorder_traversal(self):`.

Answer (score 1):

Your test functions should start with `test_`. Furthermore, if you are running `pytest` on the directory or package, your test file should also begin with `test_`:

```
# test_plates.py

from plates import is_valid


def test_two_letr():
    assert is_valid("Aa2222") == True
    assert is_valid("22aa22") == "hello"

def test_min_max():
    assert is_valid("aa3") == False
    assert is_valid("aaaa2222") == False
    assert is_valid("aa") == True
    assert is_valid("aaaa22") == True

def test_mid():
    assert is_valid("aaa22a") == False
    assert is_valid("aaa222") == True
    assert is_valid("aa2a00") == False

def test_zero():
    assert is_valid("aaa022") == False
    assert is_valid("aa0222") == False

def test_sup_space():
    assert is_valid("aaa./0") == False
    assert is_valid("aa0  ") == False
    assert is_valid("./?! ") == False
```